Show that the sum of the vectors in $K$ is a vector in $K$
Let $K$ be a finite set with at least 4 vectors such that no matter which 4 distinct vectors are chosen from $K$, there are 3 of them that have a sum of zero. Show that the sum of the vectors in $K$ is a vector in $K$.
My solution
I thought of using the rule of the polygon in our idea and the fact that by it the sum of n vectors is zero. I have no idea how to start this problem.
I could think of an example of set: $K= \{\vec{AB}, \vec{BC}, \vec{CA}, \vec{AD}   \}$  (for the last it could be any other vector)
I also tried finding such sets with 5 or more elements but couldn't. This got me thinking that maybe the set with these types of propriety cannot have only 4 elements.
what is the rule of the polygon
The polygon rule of vector addition states that if the sides of a polygon are taken in the same order to represent several vectors in magnitude and direction, then the resultant vector can be defined in magnitude and direction by the closing side of the polygon taken in the opposite order.
I found this problem in a math gathering at the vectors capitol and found it challenging so decided to ask it in this forum.

What is the rule of the polygon?

If $K$ is just a set, not a vector space, what does "sum" mean for the elements of $K$? Is $K$ supposed to be a subset of some vector space?

@MoisheKohan The vectors live in a vector space. Given any 4 vectors, there are 3 of them who can be summed and their sum is 0. (It might be possible that not all vectors live in the same vector space?) $\quad$ What exactly are you confused by?

How do you know that they are in a vector space? OP said nothing about this. I am not confused by anything.

@MoisheKohan Ah, you're wanting OP to clearly state "Let K be a finite set of vectors in the same vector space."? In any case, OP did say "sum of vectors in K", so even if K was a finite set containing vectors and other stuff, we can just limit our attention to the elements of $K$ that are vectors. Then, given any 4 of them, there are 3 which have a sum of 0, meaning that they are in the same vector space. Granted, if not all of the vectors are in the same vectors space, then we can't talk about their sum.

Actually, such a set cannot exist unless it has exactly four elements, in which case the proof is trivial.
To see this, suppose for contradiction that there exists a vector space $V$ over some field and a subset $K \subseteq V$ with $\lvert K \rvert = 5$ having the property that some 3 of any 4 elements of $K$ sum to $0$.
Write $K = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5\}$. WLOG we have $v_1 + v_2 + v_3 = 0$. Now consider the set $\{v_1, v_2, v_4, v_5\}$. We cannot have $v_1 + v_2 + v_4 = 0$ or $v_1 + v_2 + v_5 = 0$, since these would imply $v_3 = v_4$ or $v_3 = v_5$. Thus, we have (WLOG) $v_1 + v_4 + v_5 = 0$. Next, consider the set $\{v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5\}$. We cannot have $v_2 + v_3 + v_4 = 0$ since this would imply $v_1 = v_4$, we cannot have $v_2 + v_3 + v_5 = 0$ since this would imply $v_1 = v_5$, we cannot have $v_2 + v_4 + v_5 = 0$ since this would imply $v_1 = v_2$, and we cannot have $v_3 + v_4 + v_5 = 0$ since this would imply $v_1 = v_3$. Contradiction!

I am not a combinatorialist, but surely there is some theory here. Basically, the obstruction we have noticed is the following:
Theorem Let $n$ be a positive integer. Suppose there is some $\mathcal{X}  ⊆ \mathcal{P}(\{1,\dots,n\})$ such that:

$\lvert X \rvert = 3$ for all $X ∈ \mathcal{X}$,
For all $Y ∈ \mathcal{P}(\{1,\dots,n\})$ with $\lvert Y \rvert = 4$, there exists some $X ∈ \mathcal{X}$ such that $X ⊆ Y$,
For all $X, X' ∈ \mathcal{X}$, $\lvert X ∩ X' \rvert < 2$.

Then $n ≤ 4$.
Does anyone know a name for collections of subsets with this flavor? This could probably be rephrased in the language of hypergraphs or finite projective geometries.

It's unclear to me if the vectors are required to be distinct (granted OP said set instead of multi-set). $\quad$ If they are not distinct, then I can find a counterexample to the problem.

@CalvinLin They should be distinct

If by the sum of vectors in $K$ you mean
$$
\sum_{v \in K} v,
$$
then fine, we must think about it. However, if you mean that $K$ is additively stable, then it seems necessary to impose that $0 \in K$; otherwise, $K$ would not be additively stable.
Indeed, suppose that $K$ is additively stable. Since $\# K \geq 4$, there exist distinct vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4 \in K$ with $v_i \neq v_j$ for all $i \neq j$. Consider the following sets:
$$
U = \{v_i + v_j : i, j \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\},~ i \neq j\},  
$$
$$
V = \{u + v_j : u \in U, j \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \setminus \{\text{indices of } u\}\},  
$$
where by "indices of $u$", I mean the indices of the vectors $v_i$ that make up $u$. Finally, define
$$
W = \{v_1 + v_2 + v_3 + v_4\}.
$$
Thus, $U$, $V$, and $W$ are subsets of $K$. Let $w = v_1 + v_2 + v_3 + v_4 \in W$. By assumption, $w = v_{i^*}$ for some $i^*$, because
$$
v=\sum_{\substack{i = 1 \\ i \neq i^*}}^4 v_i = 0.  
$$
But $v \in V \subset K$, then $0\in K$.
Nota: I should have written this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.
